# JFrame transition over button click

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have created two GUIs in netbeans (one login form, another to add data or whatsoever).

The problem is, I do not know how to make the other form appear after I close the login button's dialog box.

In below I am posting the source codes of two frames.
The first one is for login, and the second for the other frame.

```
package hms;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        setTitle("Login");
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        UsernameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        PasswordLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        UsernameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        PasswordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        LoginButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        CancelButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("HMS Login");
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 721, 410));
        setIconImages(null);
        setMaximizedBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 721, 410));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(3276, 3276));
        jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        jPanel1.setName(""); // NOI18N

        UsernameLabel.setText("Username:");

        PasswordLabel.setText("Password:");

        UsernameTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                UsernameTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        UsernameTextField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                UsernameTextFieldKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        PasswordField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                PasswordFieldActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        PasswordField.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                PasswordFieldKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        LoginButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 255));
        LoginButton.setText("Login");

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, LoginButton, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${action.enabled}"), LoginButton, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("selected"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        LoginButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                LoginButtonMouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                LoginButtonMouseReleased(evt);
            }
        });
        LoginButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        CancelButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 255, 255));
        CancelButton.setText("Cancel");
        CancelButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CancelButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/hms/login icon.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(LoginButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 88, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                        .addComponent(CancelButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(UsernameLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(PasswordLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 93, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(UsernameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 143, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(PasswordField))
                        .addGap(36, 36, 36)))
                .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(151, 151, 151)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(UsernameLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(UsernameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(PasswordLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(PasswordField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(CancelButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(LoginButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(729, 444));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void UsernameTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                 

    private void PasswordFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                             

    private void LoginButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                        

    private void LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    }                                           

    private void UsernameTextFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void PasswordFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void LoginButtonMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Login");
    }                                         

    private void CancelButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        System.exit(0);
    }                                            

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton CancelButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton LoginButton;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField PasswordField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel PasswordLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel UsernameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField UsernameTextField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Second One -

```
package hms;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class APPTAB extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form APPTAB
     */
    public APPTAB() {
        setTitle("Hospital Management System");
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        CredentialsTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        FirstNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        FirstNameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        ADDButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        LastNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        LastNameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        MessageLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        CategoryComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        CategoryLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        IDSSNLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        IDSSNTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("HOSPITAL MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 590, 423));
        setMaximizedBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 590, 423));

        CredentialsTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "First Name", "Last Name", "Category", "ID / SSN"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(CredentialsTable);

        FirstNameLabel.setText("First Name:");

        ADDButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 204, 255));
        ADDButton.setText("Add");
        ADDButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ADDButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        LastNameLabel.setText("Last Name:");

        MessageLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));

        CategoryComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Doctor", "Patient" }));

        CategoryLabel.setText("Category:");

        IDSSNLabel.setText("ID / SSN:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(149, 149, 149)
                        .addComponent(CategoryLabel)
                        .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                        .addComponent(CategoryComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(149, 149, 149)
                        .addComponent(IDSSNLabel)
                        .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                        .addComponent(IDSSNTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(270, 270, 270)
                        .addComponent(ADDButton))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(97, 97, 97)
                        .addComponent(MessageLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 377, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(97, 97, 97)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 380, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(149, 149, 149)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(FirstNameLabel)
                                .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                                .addComponent(FirstNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(LastNameLabel)
                                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                                .addComponent(LastNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap(113, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                        .addComponent(FirstNameLabel))
                    .addComponent(FirstNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                        .addComponent(LastNameLabel))
                    .addComponent(LastNameTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                        .addComponent(CategoryLabel))
                    .addComponent(CategoryComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                        .addComponent(IDSSNLabel))
                    .addComponent(IDSSNTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(ADDButton)
                .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                .addComponent(MessageLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(51, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void ADDButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        MessageLabel.setText("");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)CredentialsTable.getModel();
        if(!FirstNameTextField.getText().trim().equals("")){
        model.addRow(new Object[]{FirstNameTextField.getText(),CategoryComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(),LastNameTextField.getText(),IDSSNTextField.getText()});
    }                                         
        else{
        MessageLabel.setText("All fields are mandatory!");
        }
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(APPTAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(APPTAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(APPTAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(APPTAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new APPTAB().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton ADDButton;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> CategoryComboBox;
    private javax.swing.JLabel CategoryLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTable CredentialsTable;
    private javax.swing.JLabel FirstNameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField FirstNameTextField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel IDSSNLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField IDSSNTextField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel LastNameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField LastNameTextField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel MessageLabel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry this is not the way we operate here. You have a specific problem, track it down with **minimal code** and we'll try to help...

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) And a tip for @MouseEvent: `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve]. Shorter to type, but resulting in more information via a link that is cited in 2 close reasons. ;)

Comment: *"I am on a hurry with this one and hope anyone would help me with that."* It's counter-productive to mention a tight schedule or allude to poor time-management practices. I for one (of many) prefer helping people when I feel like it, who don't imply their question is more urgent or time-sensitive than the questions of other people, asked here. See [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/418556) (basically: never)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Cool! Thanks for the tip.